# Foreach json output and store in variables

Tags: php, json

I am trying to foreach the result from a json code. 
I have checked the json result at jsonlint and it's validated.

I do this:

```
$result = curl_exec($curl);
if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
curl_close($curl);
```

Then when i do echo $result this is the result:

> {"vat":{"640252":{"name":"0%","percentage":"0.00","invoice_type":"2","vat_code":"5B2","available":"1"},"640258":{"name":"0%","percentage":"0.00","invoice_type":"1","vat_code":"1E1","available":"1"},"640256":{"name":"21%","percentage":"21.00","invoice_type":"1","vat_code":"1A2","available":"1"}}}

when i do this it does show the name of vat code 640252:

```
$result2 = json_decode($result, true);
echo $result2['vat']['640252']['name'];
```

But i cannot go through the json with a foreach. To start would like to make a variable with the id (like 640252) and one with the percentage, and echo them in the foreach.

I have tried a lot of things from Stackoverflow but all the json output seems to look different from the output that i have.

I hope that someone can help me in the right direction.

Comment: Well that was easy, i think i have got it now. I have read something about that way, but i didn't understand what that => meant, but i think i do now. Thank you very much Sean.

Answer (score 0):

The reson is, that the vat is a key with a value array after decoding the json string. Just iterate the vat property as in the following example.

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);

foreach ($data['vat'] as $id => $item) {
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($id, $item);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$json = '... lots of JSON here ...';

$arr = json_decode($json, true);

foreach ($arr['vat'] as $id => $item) {
    echo "$id -> {$item['name']}\n";
}
```

Using your JSON as an example, this is the output that I get:

```
640252 -> 0%
640258 -> 0%
640256 -> 21%
```

If you don't need the ID (e.g. `640252`) you can just do:

```
foreach ($arr['vat'] as $item) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would suggest to format your json to be readable for you. Personally I use https://jsonlint.com/ to validate my json data.

If we do that, we can see that vat is a json object which haves those 640252, 640258 etc as direct child's.

Decoding with second parameter as true, will decode as associative array. Looping over the vat properties would be:

```
foreach($result2['vat'] as $id => $val) {
    echo 'Id is:'. $id;
    echo 'name is '. $val['name'] ;
    echo 'percentage is '. $val['percentage'] ;
}
```

Comment: Forgive me for some additional/missing formatting. I'm writing from my phone